# FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android

Tags: android

i have an error "FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android" in fragment

this is my button :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/kirim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload" />
```

and this is code to call button

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);

kirim = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.kirim);

kirim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            simpan();

        }
    });
return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FloatingActionButton can not be cast to Button. Replace this line:

`kirim = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.kirim);`

with this line of code:

`kirim = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.kirim);`

Comment: Still an error "Error:(71, 17) error: incompatible types: FloatingActionButton cannot be converted to Button"

Comment: im sorry your answer is true. i forget to change "private Button kirim;" to "private FloatingActionButton kirim;"

Answer (score 1):

You cast `FloatingActionButton` to a `Button` , this will make an error since `FloatingActionButton` does not extend Button. Cast it properly as what the error says

```
kirim = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.kirim);
```

Comment: tanksyou for answer